# Issues Advancing in freeCodeCamp's Database Course: Need to Restart CodeRoad After Each Step for Changes to Take Effect

Tags: bash, docker, terminal

I'm currently taking the freeCodeCamp database course, specifically the introductory module "Learn Bash by Building a Boilerplate". However, I've encountered a problem that is hindering smooth progress in the course.

Every time I complete a step or exercise in CodeRoad, I have to restart the application for the changes I made to be recognized and proceed to the next step. This becomes quite bothersome and disrupts the flow of my work.

I would like to understand why this issue is occurring and if there is a solution to avoid having to restart CodeRoad after each step. Are there any configuration settings I can adjust or best practices I can follow to ensure changes are automatically recognized?

I'm using the browser version to run VSCode and CodeRoad.

I appreciate any guidance or advice you can provide. Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried restarting the page, closing the terminal with the "exit" command, and reopening it, hoping that the problem would be resolved. However, the only way I found so far is to click the "reset" button in CodeRoad before solving each step. By doing this, I temporarily manage to make it work correctly.

Comment: Sounds like a question for CodeRoad's support or developer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer support question, not a programming question